# About UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE on android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm using gmail api and auth2.0 to get the access token in my code. Then it met the error `UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE` when I debug. I have already registered it on Google Api console, got the `APIKEY` and auth client using `SHA1` and package name, but it doesn't work at all. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by myself.
The hint words on the API Console are just not precise. We should fill in the "package name" blank with the property of *applicationId* in ***build.gradle*** file instead of the package name in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** when these two are different.